# Mousedown event on multilayer elements [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a div element placed on top of a canvas (with absolute positioning). Is there a way to make canvas.addEventListener('mousedown,......) work when the user clicks on the div element? I know logically it shouldn't worked as div is placed on top of canvas and user is ultimately clicking div element, not canvas. Will making div element transparent or something work? or is there any other possible solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For newer browsers you can use CSS [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```
.div_class {pointer-events : none}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qCM9L/)

Comment: I'm using Chrome. and nope, that didn't work, clicking inside div still don't go into eventlistener for canvas...

Comment: yea. sorry, i was placing it at the wrong place. But i dont want to make all the divs unresponsive to the pointer events as i have some buttons placed in some divs. The div i want irresponsive is the one i'm making on run time:
div = document.createElement('div');
     div.id = widget.id;
     
     div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.top = y + 80;
div.style.left = x + 185;
div.style.border= '#FFF';

So how to make pointer-events:none for this particular div on runtime. (sorry i'm pretty new to javascript)